# C# pares json string to "\"String\""

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We have 2 mvc applications
When we send JSON data from the view to the controller with an ajax call.

(the code from both the controller and view are 100% identical)

```
var JsonData = {"Name" : "Jon Jonssen", "Foo": "test", "Date": new Date(2010,02,02)}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Action("TestJson")",
    data: JsonData,
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Model:

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult TestJson(JsonModel JsonModel)
```

Application 1 gets the object as following:

```
Name = "Jan Janssen"
Foo = "test"    
Date = 2-2-2010 00:00:00
```

Application 2 gets the following:

```
Name = "\"Jan Janssen\""    
Foo = "\"test\""    
Date = 1-1-0001 00:00:00
```

We can't seem to find any difference. Any help would be nice.

Comment: what's the difference between the two applications?

Comment: Please post the actual code. How can the controller and view code be identical?

Comment: The data which you passed to ajax for Application 2 must have double qouts or something. Please check.

Comment: No we checked with Chrome the postback data it is the same. 
And we know the code is identical because we copied and pasted it to test if that worked.

Comment: The applications should be almost the same but maybe there can be a setting for this somewhere but we cant find where.

Comment: i added some code but i don't think the problem is in the code

Comment: `JsonData` looks malformed.

Comment: Small error in adding some stuff now jsondata is how it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
data: JsonData
```

with:

```
data: JSON.stringify(JsonData)
```

The reason you need to do this is because you have specified `contentType: "application/json"` in your HTTP request so you must respect this settings and send JSON.

Also if you properly set the response `Content-Type` header to `application/json` (which happens under the covers if you return a JsonResult from your controller action) you don't need to specify explicitly the `dataType: 'json'`. jQuery will automatically infer this from the header.

Comment: what about `dataType` json? I thought JQuery handled that under the covers.

Comment: yes, let me update my answer. But this doesn't have anything to do with the request and the model binder. It's more about saving one line of code in the AJAX request for the response.

Comment: But why does it parse it good in the 1st application and not in the other one.

Comment: Maybe there are some custom model binders in the first application. Hard to tell without knowing more details. In an out of the box ASP.NET MVC application it won't parse it properly. Maybe it's exactly because you have such custom stuff in the first application you didn't need to `JSON.stringify` the request - as this was somehow handled on the server. But once again in a default app, it won't work. Also you are kind of violating the spec by telling the server that you are sending `application/json` and finally sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded content.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. The problem is we use a plugin in both that handles making the json calls so that Json.stringify is not posible.
We made this small test to test with some smaller things but the same as they have so we could find out the problem but i will look for custom model binders

Comment: OK, then make sure that you use the same plugin in both application so that it knows how to interpret your broken request. And yes it's a broken request because you are specifying one content type and then sending it in a completely different format. I cannot possibly imagine why would anyone want to do that: send a broken request and then *fix it* on the server with some custom code assuming that this is already built into the core framework. But maybe you have some good reasons for doing it, so I can't give any more suggestions to this.

Comment: Thanks for your help after some better searching we found a modelbinder that was said in the global.asax.cs from the plugin we use. Thank you for all your help.